# Apply CORS Polices for all API's in a APIM product

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to create a policy that applies CORS setting in all api's in a product

## Product Policies

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>GET</method>
            </allowed-methods>
        </cors>
        <base />
    </inbound>
   </policies>
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at  from origin 'url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score 0):

You can configure CORS policy for a product. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies)
[image]